# How does dedicated Server notifies Cliens about each other in p2p (TCP)

Tags: c++, linux, networking, tcp, p2p

I am learning about network programming and I want to create a simple P2P network based on TCP connection.

So far I have a server that accepts connections from clients (TCP). Clients know about server's initial location.

These are my questions:

1. How can server notify clients about each other? is it the matter of simply sending a list of every bodies IP addresses to everybody ?
2. If all clients are running on the same machine (eg 127.0.0.1), do they need to use a different port number when connecting between each other ?
3. If I want to maintain a TCP connection, how do peers decide who is going to be a client and who is a server in each pair? Perhaps this can be done on server side when he is sending off information out to clients.

I assume that TCP connection is not ideal in this scenario, at least for the reason that clients have to maintain a separate connection for each peer in a network. Although this is more of a training exercise and I looking for a reliable connection, where I don't have to deal with possibility of some packets been lost/out of order. (at this stage:).

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For question one it's up to your design, but informing connected clients in regular intervals about other clients is one way to do it.

As for the second question, if a client also should act as a server for other clients, then they have no choice as each client needs to bind to a local address (ip-address/port-number pair) and if one port on a specific ip-address is used then you have to pick another. This can be automated by setting the port to zero when binding, and the operating system will pick a port for you.

As for the third question, why can't a client be both client and server? Clients connect to the central server, which keeps track all clients in the network, and probably also handles queries from clients. When the central server receives a query it sends it to all other connected clients, and replies back to the querying client about what other clients have whatever it searches for. Then the originating client connects to the other clients that have whatever it searched for, and then those clients acts as servers for the original client.

Something like this:

1. Client A, B, C, and D connects to server
2. Client A sends query to server
3. Server sends query on to client B, C and D
4. Client B and D replies that they have what was queried
5. Server send the information back to client A
6. Client A connects to clients B and D

Now clients B and D are acting as both clients and servers. It also solves your first problem, in that the server only send information about other clients when needed.

Answer (score 1):

1. I think the answer is yes.
2. You can also use other Linux IPC mechanisms, like shared memory, rather than socket for the clients on the same server
3. Server/Client role is differentiated when connection is established: server is listening/accepting and client is connecting. After connection is established, they are in peer to peer relation.